# Maximize sum of $k$ highest numbers

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $A$ be a set such that for each $1\leq i<j\leq n$, exactly one of the ordered pairs $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ is in $A$.

For each $i<j$, let $b_{i,j}$ be the size of the intersection of $A$ and $$\{(x,y)\mid x\in\{i,j\}, y\in \{1,\dots,n\}\backslash\{i,j\}\}.$$

Let $k\leq \binom{n}{2}$. Suppose we want to choose $A$ to maximize the sum of the $k$ highest $b_{i,j}$. Is it true that we can do this by choosing $A$ so that $(i,j)\in A$ for all $i<j$?

(The reason we could expect this to be true is that this choice allows the highest $b_{ij}$ to be very high.)

Comment: what are we choosing here? the wording of the question is ambiguous. A seems to be fixed. Are we choosing the best b's?

Comment: It seems that the problem is to choose $A$ such that the $k$ highest $b_{i,j}$ are maximised.

Comment: Vincent is right.